# Duplicate ERROR is Not shown In mongodb

Tags: mongodb

_id is said to be unique as it is auto generated by mongoDB .But if i generate the _id on my own and run concurrently No Duplicate Key error is Thrown .What happens to such Datas with same _id ,will it get skipped or it doesn't even look into such type of datas

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this link
http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html

use 'WriteConcern' to that collection , if  you insert duplicate value for '_id' it  will return error message ,
for example if you access through java code, use below code

```
 collection.setWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(1));
   try{
            BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
            document.put("_id", 1);
            document.put("name", "Tamil");
            document.put("age",123);
            document.put("DOB",02-03-1991);

            collection.insert(document);

        } catch (Exception ie) {

            System.out.println("Exception in Write Operation: "+ie.getMessage());

        }
```

Comment: Thanks radhaKrishnan .It worked

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` is the [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) for documents,

> MongoDB to reject all documents that contain a duplicate value for the indexed field.  If there is more than one document without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.
>
> ```
> WriteResult({
>    "nInserted" : 0,
>    "writeError" : {
>       "code" : 11000,
>       "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.collection.$a.b_1 dup key: { : null }"
>    }
> })
> ```

As the error shown no document will be inserted into db for duplicate key.

Comment: This is shown in Console Zangw .But Iam trying to do insert ,update etc using thread  using a java test class.At that time it doesn't show Duplicate Key Error . I need to know Why it Doesn't show while running from java Test class